# Using preg_replace to replace string inside

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
<?php

$str = htmlspecialchars('<nav><a>something</a></nav>');

$pattern = htmlspecialchars('/<nav><a>something</a></nav>/i');

echo htmlspecialchars(preg_replace($pattern, '<nav> <a href="hi">click</a> 

</nav>', $str));

?>
```

I need PHP to `echo` like this:

```
<nav> <a href="hi">click</a> </nav>
```

But it's showing this error:

> Warning: preg_replace() expects parameter 4 to be int, string given in
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/Workaera/Sample.php on line 19

Comment: There is no pattern in `$pattern`. Try `stripos()` instead of preg_replace.

Comment: <nav><a>something</a></nav> this is the required pattern mentioned,

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to escape slashes. This code works:

```
$str = htmlspecialchars('<nav><a>something</a></nav>');

$pattern = htmlspecialchars('/<nav><a>something<\/a><\/nav>/i');

echo htmlspecialchars(preg_replace($pattern, '<nav> <a href="hi">click</a> 

</nav>', $str));

?>
```

But in your case preg_replace is probably overkill. Try just str_replace instead:

```
$str = htmlspecialchars('<nav><a>something</a></nav>');

$pattern = htmlspecialchars('<nav><a>something</a></nav>');

echo str_replace($str, $pattern, '<nav> <a href="hi">click</a> 

</nav>', $str);
```

Comment: Right. But OP have a `/i` modifier. Maybe use `str_ireplace()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is not valid, because of the unescaped forward slashes in HTML closing tags.

What you should be doing is something like

```
//escape HTML
$htmlEscapedPattern = htmlspecialchars('<nav><a>something</a></nav>');
//escape slashes
$forwardSlashEscapedPattern = str_replace("/", "\/", $htmlEscapedPattern);
//wrap as regex pattern
$pattern = "/" . $forwardSlashEscapedPattern . "/i";
```

Comment: You should provide more information then, as this snippet returns the exact result you are expecting. Also note that in your original code you are printing escaped HTML with `htmlspecialchars`, but in the expected output the HTML is not escaped. If that is the problem just `echo` without escaping, e.g `echo preg_replace($pattern, '<nav> <a href="hi">click</a> </nav>', $str);`

Answer (score 0):

use the following php code to get your desired result.

```
$str = htmlspecialchars('<nav><a>something</a></nav>');
$pattern = htmlspecialchars('/<nav><a>something<\/a><\/nav>/i');
echo htmlspecialchars(preg_replace($pattern, '<nav> <a href="hi">click</a> </nav>', $str));
```